# MapStruct not autowring with Spring-boot testing Gradle Junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am trying to use mapstruct with Gradle, but I am having limited success. When I'm using it in the application everything seems to be working fine, but when I tried to write some tests Spring can't autowire MapStruct properly (it just returns NullPointer exceptions). I am using Gradle 5.4.1, Junit5 and IntelliJ 2019.1.2.

This is the build folder and there is no mapper generated for test classes.

[image]

Repository with the code is here:
https://github.com/MirkoManojlovic/mapstruct-example

#### Mapper:

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN,
        componentModel = "spring",
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface ItemMapper {
    ItemDto toDto(Item item);
    Item toItem(ItemDto itemDto);
}
```

#### Repository:

```java
public class ItemRepository {
    public ItemDto getItemDto() {
        return new ItemDto("item 1");
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return new Item(1, "item 1", 20);
    }
}
```

#### Service:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class ItemService {
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final ItemMapper itemMapper;

    public ItemDto getItemDto() {
        Item item = itemRepository.getItem();
        ItemDto itemDto = itemMapper.toDto(item);
        log.info(itemDto);
        return itemDto;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        ItemDto itemDto = itemRepository.getItemDto();
        Item item = itemMapper.toItem(itemDto);
        log.info(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

#### Test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ItemServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private ItemService itemService;

    @Spy
    private ItemMapper itemMapper;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnItemDto() {
        Item mockItem = new Item(1, "mockItem", 10);
        given(itemRepository.getItem()).willReturn(mockItem);
        ItemDto itemDto = itemService.getItemDto();
        assertThat(mockItem.getName()).isEqualTo(itemDto.getName());
    }

}
```

#### build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.mapstruct.spring.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    // JUnit5
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.2'

    // Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4'
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) not sure of that is a problem I would have placed it.,

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I'm using JUnit5, and I think RunWith is replaced with ExtendWith.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Can you try setting up @Import(value={ItemMapperImpl.class}) I think the mapper implementation may not have been component scanned.

Comment: Or @SpringBootTest(classes = {ItemMapperImpl.class})

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov - I have tried @Import(value={ItemMapperImpl.class}) above the test class still nothing. And the idea is that this should be a Unit test, that's why I don't want to use @SpringBootTest(classes = {ItemMapperImpl.class}) .

Comment: Indeed, but in your code you expect that somehow th unit test will figure out the dependency injection @Spy
    private ItemMapper itemMapper;  and without Spring there is no way for it to figure out what the implementation is. Maybe you should initialize the ItemMapper using Mappers.getMapper() this way it will figure out what the implementation is.

Comment: Notice that on the mapper annotation you are specifying spring based injection strategy.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov - Yeah you are right I am dumb as a rock. When I added

```java
@Spy
private ItemMapper itemMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ItemMapper.class);
```

the test passed successfully hehe :).
I guess I will add this as a bean in a Configuration class so I can use it in all of my tests and then add @ContextConfiguration. Thank you, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Congratz :) I will summarize the answer. please accept.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov - Sure thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Spy annotation on

```
@Spy
private ItemMapper itemMapper;
```

will not perform dependency injection of the generated ItemMapperImpl class file. The solution would be to set

```
 @Spy
 private ItemMapper itemMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ItemMapper.class);
```

Or alternativly to enable spring dependency injection via `@SpringBootTest(classes = {ItemMapperImpl.class}).`